# How to get specific user's data when clicked on a button of a cardview of a recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am developing a matrimony application in which I have retrieved all the users data in cardview of a recyclerview. There is a button on each card which will show whole profile of that person on which card you have clicked. But I am getting all the users data on that page. What should I do to solve this problem ?
[image: These are the users in database]
[image: These are the sub nodes]

This is code for recyclerview:

```
 public class Search_Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Firebase firebase;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter ;

    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_detail);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.viewProfile);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Search_Profile.this));

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Search_Profile.this);

        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data from Firebase Database");

        progressDialog.show();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Dashboard.Database_Path);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    assert user != null;
                    System.out.println(user.getFirst_name()+" "+user.getLast_name());
                   // System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(user.getDate());
                    System.out.println(user.getUser_id());
                    System.out.println(user.getHeight());
                    System.out.println(user.getHighest_education());
                    System.out.println(user.getOccupation());
                    list.add(user);
                }
                adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(Search_Profile.this,list);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

    }
    }
```

This is code for Recyclerview adapter:

```
 public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Firebase firebase;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    Context context;
    List<User> MainImageUploadInfoList;
    RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<User> TempList) {

        this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;

        this.context = context;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final User user = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

        holder.FirstNameTextView.setText(user.getFirst_name()+" "+user.getLast_name());
        holder.DateTextView.setText(user.getDate());
        holder.HeightTextView.setText(user.getHeight());
        holder.EducationTextView.setText(user.getHighest_education());
        holder.OccupationTextView.setText(user.getOccupation());
        holder.UserIDTextView.setText(user.getUser_id());
        holder.ViewProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Dashboard.Database_Path);
                databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (user.getUser_id()!=null){
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                            Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                            it.putExtra("first_name", user.getFirst_name());
                            it.putExtra("last_name", user.getLast_name());
                            it.putExtra("date", user.getDate());
                            it.putExtra("height", user.getHeight());
                            it.putExtra("city_state", user.getCity_state());
                            it.putExtra("hobbies", user.getHobbies());
                            it.putExtra("highest_education", user.getHighest_education());
                            it.putExtra("occupation", user.getOccupation());
                            it.putExtra("income", user.getIncome());
                            it.putExtra("marital_status", user.getMarital_status());
                            it.putExtra("family_members", user.getFamily_members());
                            it.putExtra("fathers_name", user.getFathers_name());
                            it.putExtra("mothers_name", user.getMothers_name());
                            it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", user.getFathers_occupation());
                            it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", user.getMothers_occupation());
                            it.putExtra("user_id", user.getUser_id());
                            context.startActivity(it);

                        } }}

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView FirstNameTextView;
        //public TextView LastNameTextView;
        public TextView DateTextView;
        public TextView HeightTextView;
        public TextView EducationTextView;
        public TextView OccupationTextView;
        public TextView UserIDTextView;
        public Button ViewProfile;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            FirstNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            DateTextView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            HeightTextView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            EducationTextView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            OccupationTextView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            UserIDTextView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            ViewProfile=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewProfile);
        }
    }
    }
```

This is code of view profile:

```
 public class ViewProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
   String user_id;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6,tv7,tv8,tv9,tv10,tv11,tv12,tv13,tv14,tv15,tv16;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    //DatabaseReference uidRef;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    User user=new User();
    DatabaseReference reference;
    public static final String Firebase_Server_URL = "https://baghbanshadi-25553.firebaseio.com/User/";
    Firebase firebase;
    public static final String Database_Path = "User";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_profile);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView17);
        tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView18);
        tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);
        tv7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView20);
        tv8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
        tv9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
        tv10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView23);
        tv11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView24);
        tv12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView25);
        tv13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView26);
        tv14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView27);
        tv15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView28);
        tv16 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView29);


            String first_name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("first_name");
            tv1.setText(first_name);
            String last_name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("last_name");
            tv2.setText(last_name);
        String date= getIntent().getExtras().getString("date");
        tv3.setText(date);
        String user_id= getIntent().getExtras().getString("user_id");
        tv4.setText(user_id);
        String height= getIntent().getExtras().getString("height");
        tv5.setText(height);
        String highest_education= getIntent().getExtras().getString("highest_education");
        tv6.setText(highest_education);
        String occupation= getIntent().getExtras().getString("occupation");
        tv7.setText(occupation);
        String city_state= getIntent().getExtras().getString("city_state");
        tv8.setText(city_state);
        String hobbies= getIntent().getExtras().getString("hobbies");
        tv9.setText(hobbies);
        String income= getIntent().getExtras().getString("income");
        tv10.setText(income);
        String marital_status= getIntent().getExtras().getString("marital_status");
        tv11.setText(marital_status);
        String family_members= getIntent().getExtras().getString("family_members");
        tv12.setText(family_members);
        String fathers_name= getIntent().getExtras().getString("fathers_name");
        tv13.setText(fathers_name);
        String mothers_name= getIntent().getExtras().getString("mothers_name");
        tv14.setText(mothers_name);
        String fathers_occupation= getIntent().getExtras().getString("fathers_occupation");
        tv15.setText(fathers_occupation);
        String mothers_occupation= getIntent().getExtras().getString("mothers_occupation");
        tv16.setText(mothers_occupation);


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do it, by getting the current position

```
adapter.get(position);
```

Comment: where should I put this line in Recyclerview adapter

Comment: in your onBindViewHolder() method in the Adapter File

Comment: adapter is which function's object?